# How to view Svn detailed log in IntelliJ

Tags: svn, logging, intellij-idea, message

How to view Svn detailed log in IntelliJ ?.

Under "Messages" tab it shows error messages coming from svn server hook script redirected to stderr. How to view this as detailed log messages ( Similar to CVS Log, which can be enabled in IntelliJ ) .

If it gives option to view & copy it will help in debugging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Intellij is configured to output the logs in `C:\Users\<user>\.IntelliJIdeaXX\system\log`.

It contains dozen of information and I managed to find out the svn errors in there.

HIH

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac log output goes into `/Users/<user>/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea12`.  It will contain log files and thread dumps.